# Finding the forward distance between points in a circular list in Python

Tags: python, loops, combinations

An example circular list I would use is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, similar to the squares in a board game where the square 0 follows the square 7. I am trying to find the distance between any two points by only moving in the forward direction, rather than the minimum distance. For example, the distance between 0 and 7 would be 7, but the distance between 7 and 0 would be 1. The distance between 7 and 7 would 0, and so on. I have tried using cycle generators from iterators, but have been unable to come up with a solution as I can't understand how to approach this problem. I would really appreciate any help, thanks a lot :)!

Comment: (p1 - p0) mod size

Comment: Show some code. Show how you index your points and how you store them.

Comment: What if the list is not monotone and evenly increasing? How would calculate for that lose scenarios?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus (p1 - p0) mod size ... now, it gets more complicated if the elements aren't unique, but it still boils down to the above.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, true, you are right. Did not see he use for a board game. So it cannot have some complex number etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

def fxn(point_a, point_b):
    count = 0
    position = numbers.index(point_a)
    while numbers[position] != point_b:
        if position + 1 == len(numbers):
            position = 0
            count += 1
        else:
            position += 1
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try something based on the index as well like -

```
def dist(ind1, ind2):
    if ind1 > ind2:
        return len(x[ind1:]) + len(x[:ind2])
    else:
        return len(x[ind1:ind2])
```

Where `ind1` and `ind2` are your two indices

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop back the index using modulus operation, short and crisp.

```
l =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
def cal_dist(p1, p2):
    ct = 0
    n = len(l)
    pos = l.index(p1)
    while l[pos] != p2:
        pos = (pos+1)%n
        ct=ct+1
    return ct
```

Keep asking , keep growing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> def find_dst(l, a, b):
...     d = l.index(b) - l.index(a)
...     return d if d>=0 else len(l)+d
... 
>>> find_dst(lst, 2, 4)
2
>>> find_dst(lst, 4, 2)
6
>>>
```